# GTK syntax highlighting

Tags: gtk, syntax-highlighting

I have downloaded Cherrytree , a note-taking software endowed with syntax highlighting, to use it as a snippet manager for various programming languages. Inside a subfolder

```
gtksourceview-2.0\language-specs
```

I have found languages syntax specification files, in XML format, for example:

```
Author: Scott Martin <scott@coffeeblack.org>
<language id="js" _name="Javascript" version="2.0" _section="Scripts">
...
</language>
```

and I'm unsuccessfully looking for plain documentation, and tools if any exists, to define my own languages and relative highlighting rules.

From the folder name "gtksourceview" I  speculate that the matter is related to GTK+ framework, but that's a mere hypothesis and, anyway, https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceLanguage.html doesn't contain what I need.

Answer (score 2):

On Gnome's Developer Site you can find the [reference documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html) for language definitions as well as a [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html) which describes the creation of a new language definition.